# Intel HD card not recognized (llvmpipe instead)

Tags: 18.04, drivers, intel

Here is my target: Set up a "Kodi Box" on Ubuntu virtualized under Proxmox.

Here is my problem: Unrecognized Intel HD 620 card but llvmpipe card instead.

Here is my situation: Mini PC, i5 7200 + Intel HD 620 card, Proxmox in place for virtualization (Passthrough GPU in place to send the card to the Ubuntu VM). Ubuntu 18.04, fresh install.

Here is what I observe: The Intel card is well detected by Ubuntu; HDMI is enabled; the resolutions correspond to this card. It seems to be working properly. THE problem is that there is no acceleration; Kodi works but consumes 80% of CPU for a HD movie (the hardware works and, on Win10 or Librelec, Kodi decodes 4K with 20% of CPU). The problem seems to me related to the fact that the graphics card detected by Gnome is a "llvmpipe". A priori, it is a default solution when the "real" card is not properly installed or misconfigured. However, I do not see an error on Xorg that can explain. Direct Rendering looks OK.

Here is what I tried: As it is a VM, I could try a LOT of solutions (and rollback to try another). Many articles describe this on the net; i'v spend long hours.. now i need help...
Thanks in advance for your time.

Here are details on my configuration:

```
ekinox@hystUbuKodi:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
options i915 modeset=1

ekinox@hystUbuKodi:~$ cat /etc/default.d/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.modeset=1 i915.enable_gvt=1 i915.alpha_support=1"

ekinox@hystUbuKodi:~$ ls /lib/modprobe.d
aliases.conf  blacklist_linux-hwe_5.3.0-28-generic.conf  blacklist_linux-hwe_5.3.0-45-generic.conf  fbdev-blacklist.conf  systemd.conf

ekinox@hystUbuKodi:~$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Intel HD Graphics 620
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 ) drivers: vmware (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,intel)
           Resolution: 1440x900@59.90hz
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits) version: 3.3 Mesa 18.0.0

ekinox@hystUbuKodi:~$ sudo cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
Identifier "HD620"
Driver "intel"
Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, GPU passthrough only works when the GPU is not being used by the host OS, e.g. the host OS uses the iGPU, and the guest has a discrete GPU passed through to it.  This could definitely result in the guest falling back to `llvmpipe`.

Is there a particular reason to use virtualization?  There may be an alternate solution that would allow running Ubuntu directly on the box.  Alternatively, you could grab a cheapo dGPU off Ebay or such and pass that through to the VM. (Note that I'd go with an AMD card over Nvidia, as Nvidia's drivers don't like being ran in a VM.)

Comment: Thank you. GPU passthrough seems to work, i've unloaded GPU drivers & modules in the host, with a "lspci" command, the Intel GPU is clearly seen by Ubuntu. More over, the HDMI output works, the sound through HDMI also, the 4K definition is available => This shows me that Ubuntu see the GPU, "use it" (HDMI, sound, resolution), detect my TV ("Samsung" is detected as monitor) but there is still an issue that makes me falling with llvmpipe.

Comment: `Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 ) drivers: vmware (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,intel)`  Given that the `vmware` driver is the one being loaded, it looks like it's not passing the GPU through directly (i.e. on a PCIe level), but instead using some sort of basic acceleration through the `vmware` driver.  I'm not familiar with Proxmox or it's GPU passthrough mode, but it definitely looks like some simple accel scheme is this case rather than "true" passthrough.  Is it possible that Proxmox is failing to get exclusive access to the iGPU, and thus falling back to basic acceleration?

Comment: Also, I found this guide that has some specific parameters for iGPU passthrough: https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/guide-intel-intergrated-graphic-passthrough.30451/

Comment: Thank you. I already got the chance to read this; i've gone through again carefuly and my settings are the one proposed there. I have issues with Debian, Ubuntu or Windows 10. I will focus on Proxmox side; my problem certainly comes from there and not Ubuntu. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: No problem, always happy to help!  If my answer helped you out, consider hitting the button to mark it as the solution, it helps me out. :)